# Permission denied, though files are chmod 777

Tags: linux

Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo touch /home/test/hello.txt
sudo chmod 777 /home/test/hello.txt
sudo touch /home/test/hello1.txt
sudo chmod 777 /home/test/hello1.txt
"$(sudo du -hs /home/test/*)" >> /home/test/hello.txt
"$(sudo sort -n /home/test/hello.txt)" >> /home/test/hello1.txt
head -3 /home/test/hello1.txt
```

At line 7 it gives the error: permission denied. 
I have made both of the files chmod 777, so I have not a clue where that is comming from.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `$()` from the `du` and `sort` lines so they are like this:

```
sudo du -hs /home/test/* >> /home/test/hello.txt
sudo sort -n /home/test/hello.txt >> /home/test/hello1.txt
```

The `$()` takes the result of the operation inside the parenthesis and tries to execute it as a command. You will get various error messages if this result is not something that can be run.

Permission denied is coming up because whatever the result inside `$()` happens to be on your machine also happens to be something that you cannot execute. In my tests of your script, I also get `Is a directory` and `command not found`. It really has nothing to do with the mode of `hello.txt` or `hello1.txt`.

I should mention that I'm not exactly sure of the result you're looking for, so making the above change may or may not get you what you want.  However, the script will now run, giving you the raw `du` results in `hello.txt` and kind-of sorted results in `hello1.txt`.  You will probably need to debug the sort a little if you are trying to get a list from smallest disk usage to largest (hint: try leaving off the `-h` from `du`).